# Child Group Count values from two columns SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have datatable stuattrecordAMPM.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbiAo.jpg)

**Matrix:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IgLC.jpg)
**Output**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FZYM.jpg)

How can I have two columns expression in Matrix
I Tried: "=COUNT(IIF(Fields!INAM.Value="P" and Fields!OUTPM.Value="P",0,0))", but its showing one field columns. How to get Two column fields expression to get both "P"values.I want "P"values count.  Could someone help me on this. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!INAM.Value = "P" AND Fields!OUTPM.Value = "P", 1, 0))
```

The above checks is both AM and PM are "P" and then includes it in the sum if they BOTH are.

I did try to explain in your previous question why your expression would not work.

Here's the result based on your sample data where there are 11 days where both AM and PM and "P"

[image]

If you want to count all instances of "P" then you can use the following, which sums the two individually and then adds the results together.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!INAM.Value = "P", 1, 0)) + SUM(IIF(Fields!OUTPM.Value = "P", 1, 0))
```

Comment: In the output there is "P" values are 22 but its showing count 11. Could you please tell me how can I get 22 of "P" Count. Thanks you...

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to count all instances of "P"